# RHEL 8.4 - Unable to install httpd

Tags: redhat, rhel

I'm currently trying to install a web solution on a RHEL 8 distribution.

But I can't install apache2 (httpd) :

[image]

I search on Google but didn't find anything, and I didn't know RHEL, it's the first time

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not httpd, the issue is you have to register your system into Red Hat. See these [instructions](https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/hello-world#baremetal-alternate-license).

Answer (score 1):

there is a step-by-step to register your RHEL

**System Registration from the command line**

In the terminal window, start a root shell:

`$ sudo bash`

Next, register your system with Red Hat Subscription Management:

`# subscription-manager register --auto-attach`

Enter your Red Hat username and password.  When registration has completed, you’ll see:

```
Installed Product Current Status:
Product Name: Red Hat Enterprise Linux for x86_64
Status:       Subscribed
```

Check that you now have the BaseOS and AppStream repos enabled with yum repolist:

```
# yum repolist
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)
```

**Install updates**

Once your system has been registered, you can use the command line or web console to install the latest updates.

Updating from the command line
use `yum update` form within a Terminal session to install the latest updates.

`$ sudo yum update`

If an updated kernel package is installed during updates, you should reboot your system:

`$ reboot`

**After that you can install `httpd`**

`# yum install -y httpd`

***PRO TIP.***

***Register yourself as developer in Red Hat an redhat give you a subscription if you don't have one.This tip is for self study purposes I don't encourage you to use a developer subscription for production.***

Good journey.